# What to do with Unknown Markov State

Tags: matrix, state, transition, chain, markov

I have a state in my test dataset that did not exist in my training set (Therefore not in my transition matrix)

How can I create a transition probability simplex of this unknown state or make assumptions on the closest state to use that is available in my transition matrix?

Either to create a transition probability simplex of the unknown state or find a way to make assumptions on the closest state to use that is available in my transition matrix.